# QGIS Label Rendering in Print Composer

Tags: qgis, labeling

When I add a grid to my map in print composer, the dotted line is rendered "on top of" my map labels making them hard to read. Is there a way to make the labels appear on top of the grid lines?[image: Red circle around the label beneath the grid lines]

Answer (score 7):

I would make certain that the label is at the top of the item box in the print composer.

[image]

Then I would make certain the label had an opaque background.

[image]

From what I see, the grid is linked to the map, but the labels stand alone, so you have some control over rendering order in that respect. If you had a map with an image, and it was at the top of the item list, I believe everything beneath the map would be hidden.

Okay,
Based upon your comment, and my reply to your comment, I tried what I suggested.

[image]

I then set the desired parameters.

[image]

Then in the print composer, I created a grid with only a frame, and annotations.

[image]

It seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks, however, the labels are generated within the map, from an attribute column for the points. So on the item box the grid lines and the labels are all part of "Map 0".  It seems odd that since the grid lines are not added until the print composer, that I can't get labels to appear above them.

Comment: Sorry about that!
That is something I have never noticed before, even though I frequently add grids to my maps in the print composer.

I suppose you could create a grid layer at whatever interval you desire in the map window, then label your layers, then in the print composer you could create a grid without lines, but label the grid on the map.
I have not given that one a try as of yet, but I will later.

Comment: I added the results of my grid line test to my answer above.
It is a little bit more work, but in all it only took about five minutes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I appreciate the help, I don't think that would have occurred to me, at least it will help me make my maps more readable now. Thanks